# Rails 4 ActiveRecord::first not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm debugging some legacy code in a Rails 4.1 app and I'm seeing some confusing results from this:

```
#order.rb

# get the most recent order from the same year we are in
scope :last_from_this_year, -> { where("created_at >= ?", Time.mktime(Time.now.year, 1)).where("created_at < ?", Time.mktime(Time.now.year, 12, 31)).order('payment_id DESC').first }

# orders_controller.rb

prev_payment = Order.last_from_this_year
```

For reasons I cannot explain, this scope is returning an ActiveRecord_Relation containing ALL the order records, despite the fact that it's calling the `.first` method. I'm expecting `first` to return a single ActiveRecord object.

Why is this happening?

**Update**

When I run *this* in the console, it works as expected:

```
o = Order.where("created_at >= ?", Time.mktime(Time.now.year, 1)).where("created_at < ?", Time.mktime(Time.now.year, 12, 31)).order('payment_id DESC').first
```

I literally copy/pasted exactly what's in the `scope` and it works. So it's confusing why it doesn't behave as expected as a scope.

```
$  Order.last_from_this_year.to_sql
  =>  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders"  WHERE (created_at >= '2017-01-01 08:00:00.000000') AND (created_at < '2017-12-31 08:00:00.000000')  ORDER BY payment_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Seems right... very strange.

Comment: why do any of that? why order them to call `.first`? Why not just call `last` instead? Much lighter query. This is a really heavy query for what you're trying to return.

Comment: @toddmetheny this is legacy code that I'm debugging. I didn't write it so I can't explain "why" for any of it (and this is not even close to the messiest I've seen). At the moment I'm just trying to understand why this doesn't return anything close to what I'd expect.

Comment: Your scope looks fine. Could there be anything else messing with the result?

Comment: @CarlMarkham It seems that almost *has* to be the case, but I'm not sure what it could be. It's got me scratching my head

Comment: Technically that's an abuse of `scope`, scopes should return relations since they're meant to provide a limited *scope* for a query. That really should be a class method (explicitly so rather than implicitly by way of `scope`). Anyway, if it is return a relation then what does `Order.last_from_this_year.to_sql` say?

Comment: @muistooshort interesting. do you think maybe that's why it seems to be ignoring the `.first`?

Comment: I'm not sure, `scope` pays attention to `.first` in 4.2 but maybe 4.1 doesn't. (1) Have a look at the `.to_sql` output. (2) It should be written as a class method anyway so change to a class method.

Comment: @muistooshort I added the `.to_sql` above. I also agree about writing it as a class method. I will certainly do that as well. But I am still curious how `.first` can return a collection. Very mysterious to me.

Comment: I'm guessing that `.first` changed between 4.1 and 4.2, maybe 4.1's just tacks the `LIMIT 1` on in certain cases whereas 4.2's adds the `LIMIT 1` and always resolves the query to a single instance. The behavior could have changed somewhere between 3.x and 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept behind that scope is **wrong**. The idea of a scope is to always return an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation (a collection of objects rather than one) to allow further chaining with other methods such as `where`, `includes`, `joins`, etc.

If you need to retrieve just one object from that scope, you need to remove `.first` and use it as: `Order.last_from_this_year.first`.

Other solution is to move that code to a **class method**:

```
def self.last_from_this_year
  where("created_at >= ?", Time.mktime(Time.now.year, 1))
  .where("created_at < ?", Time.mktime(Time.now.year, 12, 31))
  .order('payment_id DESC')
  .first
end
```

Then `Order.last_from_this_year` should work as it does on the console.

Comment: But this doesn't really answer the *why* part of things. An abused `scope` in 4.2 will return a single instance whereas in 4.1 `.first` in a `scope` is apparently only throwing a `LIMIT 1` into the SQL.